# C++ multiindex column csv load

Tags: c++, csv, c++17, multi-index

Multi-index column csv is
[image]

1. Its size is (8, 8415).
2. This csv file was made from pandas multi-index dataframe (python).
3. Its columns are [codes X financial items].

codes are
[image]

financial items are
[image]

How can I use this csv file to use its year(2014, 2015, ....) as index and codesXfinancial items as multi columns?

Comment: Please show the desired result of one or two lines. E.g. in the shape of a [mre] with desired data structures filled with sample data from the shown table. Provide the sample data as text, instead of a picture of text please. Ideally as a text quote from the input file, i.e. like a text editor shows it.

Comment: What you show is not a csv file. A csv file is a TEXT file where fields are separated by delimiters (generaly comma) and optionaly enclosed in quotes. You have only showed how it is interpreted in a spreadsheet application... Apart from that, I do not know what you call *multi columns* in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of output you want is unclear. There are not many libraries to imitate pandas in C++. A very messy, convoluted and inelegant way of doing it is declaring a structure and then put it into a list. Something like,

```
struct dataframe{
    double data;
    int year;
    int code;
    char item[];   //or you can use "string item;"
}
```

Make a list of this structure either by a custom class or C++ native "list" class.
If you can provide a more detailed explanation of what kind of data structure you want in the program or what do you want to do with it, I would try to provide a better solution.

Comment: Thank you! I had better make structure to use the data :-) I will try it

Comment: It's a very slow and messy method. Sorry that I couldn't help more.